# How to get the assembly information of an imported MEF function?

Tags: c#, mef, .net-assembly

Is it possible get the assembly information from an imported MEF function?  I need to know the assembly version and name of the Plugin control that contains the function.  Tried the following, but it just returns the  System.ComponentModel.Composition version.

```
foreach (Lazy<Func<int>, IMetadata> func in PluginFuncs)
{
    // get assembly information of the Plugin control for the imported function 
    string version = func.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(version);
}
```

Another alternative would be to use hardcoded values in the metadata, but I thought this would not be maintainable.  It would be easy to forget to change those values when the version changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the type from within `func.Value`, not the `Lazy<T,TMeta>` wrapping it.  Try:

```
Func<int> lambdaFunc = func.Value;
Delegate del = lambdaFunc;
string version = del.Method.ReflectedType.Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

However, realize that this will evaluate the `Lazy<T>` at this point - but this is required, because the object where you are trying to get the type hasn't be constructed until you evaluate that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but now it's returning the version for mscorlib.  Any more ideas?

Comment: @John_Sheares: Oh, damn - that makes sense - Func<T> is System.Func<T>... mmm... let me think

Comment: @John_Sheares: I believe the above will now work.  By assigning to a delegate, you can get the type on which the method is defined via the MethodInfo returned in Delegate.Method.

Comment: Reed, it worked!  Thanks again for your incredibly fast help!